# How to run a model for multiple variables(columns) in df with lmer

Tags: r, function, lmer

I have several variables(columns) in a df I want to run lmer (from lme4 package).
Say I have a dataframe called df:

```
par1   par2 resp1 resp2
plant1 rep1 3     8
plant2 rep2 5     2
...
```

I'm trying to write a function to do this, but having trouble passing arguments and using them in the function.

```
model1 = function(df, varname){
  library(lme4)
  model1 = lmer(varname ~ + (1 | par1) + (1 | par2), data=df)
  return(model1)
}

resp1model = model1(df, "resp1")
resp2model = model1(df, "resp2")
```

Can someone advise on the best way to do this?  Maybe a function isn't the answer? A loop?
I should say the reason is that once I get the function working, I want the function to return other things from the model.. such as the AIC, BLUPs, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this way, may be even better

```
varlist=names(df)[i:j] #define what vars you want

blups.models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lmer(substitute(i ~ (1|par1)+(1|par2)+(1|par3), list(i = as.name(x))), data = df, na.action=na.exclude)
})
```

here you have the list of models for all vars you want

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to substitute your line:

```
model1 = lmer(varname ~ + (1 | par1) + (1 | par2), data=df)
```

with

```
model1 = lmer(paste0(varname," ~ + (1 | par1) + (1 | par2)"), data=df)
```

This will pass the formula as a string, which `lmer(...)` will coerce to a formula.

Comment: or `form <- reformulate("~(1|par1)+(1|par2)",response=varname); lmer(form, data=df)`

Comment: Thanks!  These suggestions helped fixed my original code, but I think I'm better off with the list approach suggested by @Ananta

Comment: Hmm.  Why? I think I prefer this solution -- computing on the language (i.e. `substitute()`) always seems to me to carry more potential complexities, so I avoid it unless I absolutely need it ...

Comment: Making a list of variable names and storing the data in a list of model objects seems to be easier to work with.. then I can use lapply to do things to each model in the list.. unless I am misunderstanding the approach you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.. seems a bit more complicated.. but thought I would add it for completeness:
[R: analyzing multiple responses (i.e. dependent variables) in a mixed effects model (lme4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525633/r-analyzing-multiple-responses-i-e-dependent-variables-in-a-mixed-effects-mo)